# Proving $\cos(\pi/2^n) =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: trigonometry

WolphramAlpha gives the following identities for the cosines of $\frac{\pi}{2^n}$:

$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}
$$
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}
$$
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{32}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}
$$
and in general the following identity seems to be true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots\sqrt{2}}}
$$
With $n-1$ nested roots. Obviously for $n=2$ we have $\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}$.

I have no idea where to start to prove this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: **Hint:** Apply the cosine half angle formula $2\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}$.

Comment: Just use induction, and the identity $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you want to show for positive integer $k$

$$\cos (\pi/2^k)=\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi/2^{k-1})\over 2},$$

which follows from the [half-angle identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae).

Comment: This was a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval oups, merci de l'avoir signalé, Anne.

Comment: Donc je pense que tu devrais détruire ta réponse.

Comment: @AnneBauval J'ai essayé, mais OP doit supprimer l'acceptation pour cette réponse

Comment: Ah, d'accord! @FrankSoll can you please unaccept this answer, so that its author can delete it (as a duplicate)?